want to scheduled cron job according to dynamic variable
I have method needs to run at specific date but date can be changed according to api response so
if I created a global variable like
private String cronJobRunAt;

and this value is changed or provided by user from api.
so scheduling will change accordingly
I have used previously like this
@Scheduled(cron = "${cron-scan-interval}")

but this cron-scan-interval is taken from properties file but here I want variable value
Is it work like this?
@Scheduled(cron = "${cronJobRunAt}")


you should first be clear on the language you are using. Java doesn't support global variables. What you are describing is an instance variable. I doubt this is possible, however, whatever you have as a job that you want to start scheduled, you can no doubt also start it by calling the code, and what is stopping you from implementing it so that it  does that based on that variable?

No, you cannot dynamically change the schedule with a variable.  You can, however, create a service, inject the ScheduledTaskRegistrar, and do this in code.
